# Usage of __attribute__((aligned(4), packed)) with structures in C

Tags: c, struct, attributes, compiler-optimization

I want to use the structure to store some data and then transfer it via DMA. However, the specifics of the periphery require alignment of the initial address of the structure along the 4-byte boundary. I don't understand why using the alignment attribute in different places causes the packed structure to be resized by 1 byte.

I wrote simple example to represent this situation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdint.h"

// Version with aligned attribute
struct packet_v1 
{
    uint8_t uid;
    uint8_t flag;
    uint8_t comm;
    uint32_t a;
    
} __attribute__((packed, aligned(4)));

// Version without alignment 
struct packet_v2
{
    uint8_t uid;
    uint8_t flag;
    uint8_t comm;
    uint32_t a;
    
} __attribute__((packed));


struct packet_v1 pkt1;
struct packet_v2 pkt2 __attribute__((aligned(4)));


int main()
{
    printf("Align v1: %lu, size: %lu\r\n", (uintptr_t)&pkt1 % 4, sizeof(pkt1));
    printf("Align v2: %lu, size: %lu\r\n", (uintptr_t)&pkt2 % 4, sizeof(pkt2));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Align v1: 0, size: 8
Align v2: 0, size: 7
```

Comment: The alignment requirement is also adding a padding such that the size of the structure is divisible by the alignment. It is done for example for the case in which you might want to place these structures in array, so each element remains aligned.

Comment: This is what I needed to know, it turns out that by adding a byte to the size, the compiler guarantees alignment along the specified boundary for any member of the array of structures. And in the case of a single variable, this is not necessary. I would also be interested to know if I can get the compiler to add one byte manually (by adding some attribute) in the second case (pkt2)?

Comment: *And in the case of a single variable, this is not necessary.* - it is not, but it is still done because you want to have compatible structures of the same type across different translation units. As for the second question, you can add one extra dummy field to pad it manually. But if you have requirements for specific size, you better add some static assertions checking the requirement, as the compiler provides little guarantees regarding the exact layout.

Comment: You can specify what you mean by "different translation units"? We are talking about several compiled programs?

Comment: Think that your struct type is defined in a header file. Then it is included in several C files. Each C file is a separate translation unit which is in general compiled separately into a separate object file. So when compiling one of these, the compiler does not "know" how this struct is used in other files, so it can't make assumptions.

Comment: Therefore, does the compiler have a preferred option with padding up to a multiple of 4 bytes in the case of declaring a structure with attributes? 
And the option is only with packaging without size alignment for a variable?
I can't figure out how compatibility is ensured.

Comment: Sidenote: The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`. not `%lu`.

Comment: @Typeofundefined Adding a byte "manually" in the second case is easy. Just add a member `uint8_t padding;`. You can make this an array if multiple bytes are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct_v1` has a padding byte at the end, so that an array of structures will have each element aligned to a 4-byte boundary, as required by `aligned(4)`.

`struct_v2` has no padding byte, so that an array of structures will be packed as tightly together as possible. There's no need to align each array element the same.